# Create a "tags" in filebrowser

Tags: tags, drupal-7, file-browser

I would like my admins to be able to upload files to the website. And I need to give those files some meta data so we can filter and display related files on the frontend. Can someone offer me a good workaround to do this?

I myself have struggled with this for many weeks. I can create a new taxonomy structure and with it a view to manage all the content or I can work with existing modules (but they don't meet my expectations).
Are there hooks available to "hack" into the filebrowser, so we can select the display of files on tags?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://drupal.org/project/media and http://drupal.org/project/file_entity Media has views integration and file_entity makes files fieldable.